# deploying WAMP -> live site - any random tips?

Tags: php, mysql, security, apache

In the next few weeks I'll be taking my site from the localhost (WAMP) and puting it on [a new server](http://www.memset.com/dedicated-servers/virtual.php). This will be the first site, on my first server, so basically...i'm a noob!

This must be an important moment for any independent web developer / small  business so i'd love to hear about some experiences, mistakes and system default security holes that one should fix straight away...

**I'm using php, mysql, cpanel and WHM, and looking for tips like "Turn off error reporting in PHP"**

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost if you are worried about security then you should use LAMP.  As long as the Linux platform is using AppArmor or SELinux (Ubuntu and fedora respectively), then you are **much** better off than any version of Windows.  I know this from first hand experience of developing exploit code for the two platforms.

Before you lock your system down,  test your code for vulnerablites using [Wapiti](http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/).  [Acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com/cross-site-scripting/scanner.htm) is also good,  but expensive. This type of testing,  especially sql injection testing must be done with `dispaly_errors=On` set in your php.ini

There is a lot that can go wrong with PHP Configuration that makes your system less secure.  You should run [PHPSecInfo](http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/) and remove all red.  `dispaly_errors=Off` is what you want,  and phpsecinfo tests for it.

You should also use a web application firewall like [Mod_secuirty](http://www.modsecurity.org/).

Comment: yep i'm working with LAMP, PHPSecInfo looks like a great place to start, will check out wapiti and mod_security, thanks rook

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite a huge undertaking, but well worth the experience.  Here are just one or two suggestions...

Site security also means being heavily involved in managing your sometimes scarce resources.  Just as important is obeying any limits your host has, and guessing all possible ways your site users can push you over those limits, leaving you responsible to pay a hefty bill.  IE downloading or uploading large files over and over, spamming email lists, repeatedly requesting pages using too many database connections and queries, etc.  Get overusage limits and fees in writing from your host before you begin, and have response plans ready.  Really, this part is like buying a cellphone service.

A lot would also depend on what features you'll have on your site.  File uploads?  Forum?  Logins?  Email?  Etc?  For example - If you're running a file-sharing site: along with upload/download rate limiting, I suggest you first check available disk space before permitting any file to be uploaded, or do regular audits so you're prepared to archive or delete old and unused files.  It's a quick check just to make sure you're not caught by surprise a year down the road when you suddenly start getting disk full errors or get shafted by your host with a large bill.

There are literally a hundred more issues to consider.  Gather up a complete overview - an itemized list - of all features and functions of your site.  Google each one to get more ideas on handling security.  Your host should also publish their own security considerations and have a handy manual for operating with all of their services.  If they don't, well, I wouldn't personally feel comfortable with them.